# Wb scraping-- find_all not resulting any value

Tags: python, spyder

Am using beautiful `soup4` for web scraping, but `find_all('tables')` resulting none.

Below is my code:

```
#import the library used to query a website
import urllib.request

#specify the url  
wiki="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)

#import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data returned from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)


print (soup.prettify())

soup.title

soup.title.string

soup.a

soup.find_all("a")

all_links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
    print (link.get("href"))

all_tables = soup.find_all('tables')
```

LOG: `all_tables = soup.find_all('tables')`.

Please suggest

Comment: There are no `<tables>` tag inside that page, perhaps you mean `soup.find_all('table')`.

Comment: try rather with `all_tables = soup.find_all('table')`

Comment: tables is not a html tag. What do you want this all_tables to contain?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to print values inside tables you can do it like this:

```
for values in soup.find_all('td'):
    print(values.getText())
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your are making mistake in tag name, try below code

```
table_tags = soup.find_all("table")
```

Also, you can specify other attribute to get desired table for eg

```
table_tag = soup.find_all("table", {"class" : "wikitable"})
```

this will return table tag